# How to use Pyramid i18n outside of views and templates?

Tags: python, pyramid, python-babel

[Pyramid documentation](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.0-branch/narr/i18n.html#performing-a-translation) shows us how to use i18n inside views (and [templates as well](http://blog.abourget.net/2011/1/13/pyramid-and-mako%3a-how-to-do-i18n-the-pylons-way/)). But how to does one use it outside of views and templates where we have no access to current `request` (for example, in `forms` and `models`)?

@Michael said to pass `request` to models and forms. But is it right? I mean if form fields defines before `__init__()` method calls, the same with models. They don't see any parameters from views...

In Pylons we could simply use `get_lang()` and `set_lang()` and define preferable language in parent controller and then use `ugettext()` and `ungettext()` in any place we want without calling it from `request` directly every possible time (in views).

How to do that in Pyramid? Note that the language must be set from user's settings (session, cookies, db, etc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My solution is to create the form class when it's needed with localizer as parameter. For example

forms.py

```
class FormFactory(object):

    def __init__(self, localizer):
        self.localizer = localizer
        _ = self.localizer
        self.required_msg = _(u'This field is required.')
        self.invalid_email_msg = _(u'Invalid email address.')
        self.password_not_match_msg = _(u'Password must match')

    def make_contact_form(self):
        _ = self.localizer
        class ContactForm(Form):
            email = TextField(_(u'Email address'), [
                validators.Required(self.required_msg),
                validators.Email(self.invalid_email_msg)
            ])
            content = TextAreaField(_(u'Content'), [
                validators.Required(self.required_msg)
            ])
        return ContactForm
```

When you need to use the form

```
@view_config(route_name='front_pages.contact_us',
             renderer='myweb:templates/front_pages/contact_us.genshi')
def contact_us(request):
    """Display contact us form or send mail

    """
    _ = get_localizer(request)

    factory = FormFactory(_)
    ContactForm = factory.make_contact_form()
    form = ContactForm(request.params)
    return dict(form=form)
```

As you can see, we get the localizer in the view, and pass it to the FormFactory, then create a form with that factory. By doing that, all messages in the form was replaced with current locale language.

Likewise, you can do the same with model.

Answer (score 2):

Have you found `pyramid.18n.get_localizer` yet?

http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.3-branch/narr/i18n.html#using-a-localizer

Comment: `get_localizer()` require parametr `request`, so this mean I can use it only inside view function (or class). But how to use it outside views?

Comment: Well you access the `request` by passing it into your forms/models, or use `get_current_request()` or you make your own localizer as that link says via `make_localizer`. The `request` determines what locale should be used by the localizer, and if you want to maintain that behavior then obviously you need a `request`.

Comment: Seems like you just changed the question from "how to do translation outside of views/templates" to "how to do translation". I feel like I answered your original question in the answer and the comments with respect to how Pyramid does this. To learn how Pyramid does translation you should read the entire page I linked because it really seems to cover most of this "in practice".

Answer (score 1):

Actually I had this very same problem. What I ended up doing was to see how the default locale negotiator works - it looks for a *LOCALE* property on the given request object. So just use a dummy to create the localizer. You may cache this value too, if you want

```
def my_get_localizer(locale=None):
    request = Request({})
    request._LOCALE_ = locale

    return get_localizer(request)
```

Alternatively, join the irc channel #pyramid @ freenode and pester the guys enough there to split the functionality of get_localizer in 2 separate documented functions (get_localizer and get_localizer_for_locale_name) for us to enjoy ;)

Also, notice that Pyramid TranslationStrings are lazy, so you can translate them as late as you want, e.g.

```
class MyModel(Base):
    description = TranslationString("My model number ${number}")

...

def view(request):
    m = MyModel()
    localizer = get_localizer(request)
    description = localizer.translate(m.description, mapping={'number': 1})
```

Sidenote: pylons' i18n was the worst can of worms I had opened in ages. The set_lang, get_lang hack was really awful, and pain in the ass as we needed to send emails to users in their native languages and then tried to restore the language back... also, it was IMPOSSIBLE to translate anything outside of a request in a pylons program, as a translator or the registry did not exist then.

Answer (score 0):

You can  make a localizer, and then translate a template accordingly.

When making the localizer, you can pass the lang you want (whether you have it from db or else). Hope it can help.

For the sake of clarity, I will set it as 'fr' below

```
from pyramid.i18n import make_localizer, TranslationStringFactory
from mako.template import Template
from mako.lookup import TemplateLookup
import os

absolute_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
tsf = TranslationStringFactory('your_domain')
mako_lookup = TemplateLookup(directories=['/'])
template = Template(filename=template_path, lookup=mako_lookup)

localizer = make_localizer("fr", [absolute_path + '/../locale/'])

def auto_translate(*args, **kwargs):
    return localizer.translate(tsf(*args, **kwargs))

# Pass _ pointer (translate function) to the context
_ = auto_translate

context.update({
    "_": _
})

html = template.render(**context)
```

***EDIT***
You can also put this logic into a small function

```
def get_translator(lang):
    """
    Useful when need to translate outside of queries (no pointer to request)
    :param lang:
    :return:
    """
    localizer = make_localizer(lang, [absolute_path + '/../locale/'])

    def auto_translate(*args, **kwargs):
        return localizer.translate(tsf(*args, **kwargs))

    _ = auto_translate

    return _
```